# I want to able to show just one row in a table depending on the ID of who logs in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, row, edit

The following code creates the columns but how can I hide all rows except the row with ID of person who has logged in.  Each row has an edit feature which I'd like to keep.

```
@grid.GetHtml(    
        tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(             
             grid.Column(format:@<ahref="~/editanimator?id=@item.ID">Edit</a>),
             grid.Column("Name"),
             grid.Column("Skills"),
             grid.Column("Email"),
             grid.Column("Reel"),
             grid.Column("Country"),
             grid.Column("Level"), 
             grid.Column(format:@<ahref="~/DeleteAnimator?id=@item.ID">Delete</a>)
```

Comment: Limit your controller to only show the record of the person who is logged in.

Comment: Thanks TK but being a total nube at coding is there any actual code you could demo for limiting with a controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of MVC you are using or what authentication your are using. It looks like you have a separate table that contains details on your users. In your controller do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  using (YourContext db = new YourContext())
  {
    //I'm not sure where you are getting the id of the logged in person.
    //Also for "Find" to work, id must be the primary key of the table.
    userinfo u = db.UserInfoTable.Find(id);   
    return View(u);
  }
}
```

That will pass only one record to your view. You should never rely on the client to provide security. Hiding records you don't want people to see is not secure. Viewing your source code will reveal the information you're hiding. It's best practice for your controller to only send the information that is absolutely necessary to render the page.

You'll need to modify the first line of your view, as you no longer will be passing a list of users.

```
@model IEnumerable<YourApp.Models.usermodel>
```

to

```
@model YourApp.Models.usermodel
```